# Force user to download a file to their hard drive via hyperlink?

Tags: web-browser, attacks

I want to design a scenario in which I have a web site which contains a link. If the user clicks on this link, it will save a file in a specific pat in his hard disk without his consent. Is this possible?

Comment: No, unless you have a 0-day exploit.

Answer (score 4):

The browser is typically sandboxed from this type of system interaction just using JavaScript, localstore, etc.

If you have plugins and can run Java Applets its possible. There should be warnings that pop up, but one could use social engineering to trick them into click this. You could probably just get them to download an executable and home their anti-malware settings don't block it.

Beyond that you would need to exploit a flaw in the browser's implementation of some spec or security design.

Some useful links:

- [Flash Sandboxing (OWASP)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Flash_Applications#SandBox_Security_Model)
- [The File System API Proposed (Dead) Spec](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)
- [Sandboxed vs Privileged JAVA Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)